# Mapping URL Pattern to a Single RequestHandler in a WSGIApplication

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Is it possible to map a URL pattern (regular expression or some other mapping) to a single RequestHandler?  If so how can I accomplish this?

Ideally I'd like to do something like this:

```
application=WSGIApplication([('/*',MyRequestHandler),])
```

So that MyRequestHandler handles all requests made. Note that I'm working on a proof of concept app where by definition I won't know all URLs that will be coming to the domain.  Also note that I'm doing this on Google App Engine if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
application=WSGIApplication([(r'.*',MyRequestHandler),])
```

for more see [the AppEngine docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/running.html)

Answer (score 8):

The pattern you describe will work fine. Also, any groups in the regular expression you specify will be passed as arguments to the handler methods (get, post, etc). For example:

```
class MyRequestHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self, date, id):
    # Do stuff. Note that date and id are both strings, even if the groups are numeric.

application = WSGIApplication([('/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/(\d+)', MyRequestHandler)])
```

In the above example, the two groups (a date and an id) are broken out and passed as arguments to your handler functions.